# How to find chinese and english character in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, chinese-locale

I have a string containing Chinese and English characters and I want to split the string into the individual Chinese and English characters.

Here are some examples:

1. hello 你好
2. 你好 你好 hello

[This page](http://flyingsky.github.io/2018/01/26/javascript-detect-chinese-japanese/) teaches how to detect Chinese character but it didn't work when splitting up the string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your test code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string at every occurrence of space at every occurrence of a 'Chinese' character, as so:

```js
  let chiStr = "你好 你好 hello"
  chiStr.split(' ')//splitting the string at every occurrence of a space
  //expected result: ["你好", "你好", "hello"]

  const REGEX_CHINESE = /[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]/u;
  const hasJapanese = (str) => REGEX_CHINESE.test(str);

  chiStr.split(REGEX_CHINESE) splitting the string at every occurrence of a 'chinese' character
  //expected result: ["你", "好", "你", "好", " hello"]
```

Another good approach is to filter out the Chinese words and the English words into separate arrays as so:

```js
const REGEX_CHINESE = /[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]/u;
const hasJapanese = (str) => REGEX_CHINESE.test(str);

const seperateWords = (str)=>{
   let newStr = str.split(' ')
   let chiWords = newStr.filter((string)=>REGEX_CHINESE.test(string))//All chinnese words
   let engWords = newStr.filter((string)=>!REGEX_CHINESE.test(string)) //All english words
   let arrayOfDiffWords = [chiWords, engWords]
   return arrayOfDiffWords
}
console.log(seperateWords("你好 你好 hello")) //test
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this npm package: https://github.com/alsotang/is-chinese

```
import isChinese from 'is-chinese'
isChinese('中国').should.true();
isChinese('中国ss').should.false();
isChinese('ss').should.false();
isChinese("\uD842\uDFB7").should.true();
```